# record ranks of numbers in a list C#

Tags: c#, linq

Question:
I have a list of list number `(List<List<int>> listNumberCollection)`: 4 rows x 3 columns

```
1 3 9
6 5 6
3 2 7
2 7 2
```

How can I record of rank in column (smallest number is the 1st) so it should be:

```
1 2 4
4 3 2
3 1 3
2 4 1
```

My work:
To order numbers in a column, I write a function for transposition (4 columns x 3 rows):

```
1 6 3 2
3 5 2 7
9 6 7 2

private List<List<Double>> MatrixTransposition(int k, List<List<Double>> listNumberCollection)
{
      var revisedAllRanks = new List<List<Double>>();
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
      {
           var allRanks = new List<Double>();
           allRanks.AddRange(listNumberCollection.Select(value => value[i]));
           revisedAllRanks.Add(allRanks);
      }
      return revisedAllRanks;
}
```

I tried to create a class named NumberRank with 2 properties (Number, Rank) and add into list of NumberRank

```
var revisedListNumberCollection = MatrixTransposition(k, listNumberCollection);
var listNumberRanks = new List<List<NumberRank>>();
foreach(List<Double> vectorsCollection in revisedListNumberCollection)
{                    
     List<NumberRank> numberRanks = vectorsCollection.OrderByDescending(number => number).Select((number, i) => new NumberRank(number, i + 1)).ToList();                        
     listNumberRanks.Add(numberRanks);
}
```

However, the result I get is ordered number with rank (first column: 1-1 2-2 3-3 6-4...), not what I want (1-1 6-4 3-3 2-2)
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really think your explanation is complete enough to make us understand what you are trying to ask?

Comment: @PawanNogariya I can understand what he means, the example is fairly clear enough, however the downvotes may be for **he doesn't try anything himself first** , not for **unclear question**.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. He wants to replace every item within column with it's index on the same column values collection being sorted.

Comment: Thanks to @MarcinJuraszek now it's clear what he wants :)

Comment: `numbers.Select((i, n) => new { i, n }).OrderBy(in => in.n).Select(in => in.i)`

Comment: @millimoose `.OrderBy(in => in.i).Select(in => in.n+1)`

Comment: @I4V Oh, right. (I guess it'd be better to just swap `i` and `n` in the first `Select()`. And give them less bad names.)

Comment: @qnguyen Well, then the above comments might actually be useful. Your problem is that you need to create the `NumberRank`s *before* sorting, not *after*.

Comment: Hi all, Sorry I did not make a clear question. I can rank numbers but the problem is I cannot record the ranks with its index on the same column values as explained by @MarcinJuraszek.

Comment: @KingKing - I am not in the down voters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with pure Linq

```
var input = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int> { 1, 6, 3, 2 },
    new List<int> { 3, 5, 2, 7 },
    new List<int> { 9, 6, 7, 2 }
};

var result = input.Select(l =>
        l.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = i}) // selecting index
         .OrderBy(z => z.x) // sorting by value
         .Select((z, j) => new { i = z.i, j = j + 1 }) // selecting rank
         .OrderBy(z => z.i) // sorting by initial index
         .Select(z => z.j)  // returning rank
         .ToList()
     ).ToList();

// List<List<int>>(3)
// {
//    List<int>(4) { 1, 4, 3, 2 },
//    List<int>(4) { 2, 3, 1, 4 },
//    List<int>(4) { 4, 2, 3, 1 } 
//}
```

**update** To transpose rows to columns and back you can do:

```
var transp_input = Enumerable.Range(0, input[0].Count)
                             .Select(i => input.Select(x => x[i]));
```

then you do calculation

```
var transp_result = transp_input.Select(l =>
        l.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = i }) // selecting index
         .OrderBy(z => z.x) // sorting by value
         .Select((z, j) => new { i = z.i, j = j + 1 }) // selecting rank
         .OrderBy(z => z.i) // sorting by initial index
         .Select(z => z.j)  // returning rank
         .ToList()
     ).ToList();
```

and transpose back

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, transp_result[0].Count)
                       .Select(i => transp_result.Select(x => x[i]).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @roman-pekar, I think the rank of 2nd list is not correct. Your result is: 3 1 2 4. It should be: 2 3 1 4. Cheers

Comment: @qnguyen sorry missed that, changed the answer.

Comment: Hi @roman-pekar, Could you sort it in column, not row?
Cheers,

Comment: I'll see what I can do in an hour

Answer (score 0):

I would go with following:

```
var input = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int> { 1, 6, 3, 2 },
    new List<int> { 3, 5, 2, 7 },
    new List<int> { 9, 6, 7, 2 }
};

var results = new List<List<int>>(input.Count);
foreach (var list in input)
{
    var rankDict = list.OrderBy(x => x).Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.v, x => x.i);
    results.Add(list.Select(x => rankDict[x] + 1).ToList());
}

foreach (var list in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Select(x => x.ToString())));
}
```

It's not pure LINQ, but do what you expect. The result is:

```
1 4 3 2
2 3 1 4
4 2 3 1
```

However, it has one limitation: it requires single list values to be unique.

Comment: This is a good answer. I wish I could vote up but I don't have enough points :)